# How to create circular camera2 preview?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I tried to create circular camera2 preview by adding TextureView in custom circular ViewGroup, but I think this is not the best way. Could anybody give me some example how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If by circular preview you mean just "masking the camera preview inside a circle", you can do it by simply using a FrameLayout with a TextureView/SurfaceView (where your camera2 preview will be) below an ImageView, which is nothing but a rectangle with a circular opening. You can set the color of the ImageView to match the background color to create a seamless experience.